# Sourcing setup.*sh files catkin

Tags: command-line, bash, ros

I have been following a catkin tutorial on the ROS wiki. I came across this:
To add the workspace to your ROS environment you need to source the generated setup file:

```
$ . ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

My question is: What is this particular syntax for sourcing? Shouldn't we use the source command? As far as I know, . refers to the current directory. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, it's `.` (dot) that is the standard command: `source` is equivalent in `bash` and some other shells. See for example [Is the shell's `source` POSIX-standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588583/is-the-shells-source-posix-standard)

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
$ source
bash: source: filename argument required
source: usage: source filename [arguments]

$ help source
source: source filename [arguments]
    Execute commands from a file in the current shell.

    Read and execute commands from FILENAME in the current shell.  The
    entries in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.
    If any ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters
    when FILENAME is executed.

    Exit Status:
    Returns the status of the last command executed in FILENAME; fails if
    FILENAME cannot be read.
```

```bsh
$ source ~/.bashother    # Valid
$ . ~/.bashother         # Valid
```

Typically, we check for the existence of the file before sourcing it, however:

```bsh
$ [[ -f ~/.bashother ]] && source ~/.bashother
```

I would recommend that you use the `source` command instead of `.`.  The main reason for this is code readability and maintainability.

By using `source`, you can more easily and accurately find places in your code base, or file system that source resources, vs searching for `.`.  If you're experiencing issues, or need to make changes, this is very helpful, especially when you aren't the only contributor.

If you want a way to create resource files and easily source them, you can setup something like this in your `.bashrc` file:

```bsh
BASHRCDIR="${HOME}/.bashrc.d"
if [ -d "$BASHRCDIR" ]; then
    find $BASHRCDIR/* -executable| while read f;
    do
        source "${f}"
    done
fi
```

Then, any `+x` file in `~/.bashrc.d/` will be loaded.  You can prefix the filenames with numbers to ensure order:

```bsh
source ~/.bashrc # Source updated .bashrc
mkdir ~/.bashrc.d/
touch ~/.bashrc.d/001-bashother
chmod +x ~/.bashrc.d/001-bashother
```

---

- [`source`](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html) is not an executable, but a `bash` command.
- `zsh` ensures the current directory is searched before `$PATH` when using `source`.
- `.` is [not valid in C shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_(command)).